# Unable to build any C++ projects on VS 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I try to *"Build"* a project it says:

**The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error**

When I try to debug the debugger says:

**The debugger cannot continue the process**

I really don't understand what is wrong with that? The project is fine and it compiles perfectly on VS 2008.

Comment: did you try to build a sample application with the Visual Studio 2010 wizzard? it may just be the installation of the tool itself that failed and you need to reinstall

Comment: With every new version of Visual Studio they come up with clearer and clearer error messages.

Comment: Post the most simplified complete code that demonstrates the issue.  Any unusual compiler settings should also be included.  When in doubt, post a step by step (with details) account of how the compiler was set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context information it's hard to help. VC10 is in Beta2 state so you should report this problem with context (environement + projects infos) to the [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) website.

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap
I didn't know that using "**Terminal**" as your output window font breaks the building/debugging process.